# Javascript - Select Tag not working inside Draggable Parent

Tags: javascript, select

I have a draggable parent in which i have select tag. Parent is entirely draggable but select tag present inside Draagable Parent is not opening

[this is jsfiddle link for the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/fkhtb5yu/1/) Please suggest what should i do to open select in this scenario
PFB the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#myModal {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9; height: 200px; width: 200px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;}
#myModalheader {
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: move;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: #2196F3;
    color: #fff;}
</style>
<script>
function ready() {
dragElement(document.getElementById("myModal"));
}
function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id)) {
  document.getElementById(elmnt.id).onmousedown = dragMouseDown;} 
  else {elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;}

  function dragMouseDown(w) {
    w = w || window.event;
    w.preventDefault();
    pos3 = w.clientX;
    pos4 = w.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;}

  function elementDrag(w) {
    w = w || window.event;
    w.preventDefault();
    pos1 = pos3 - w.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - w.clientY;
    pos3 = w.clientX;
    pos4 = w.clientY;
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";}

  function closeDragElement() {
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;}}

      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myModal">
  <div id="myModalheader">Click here to move</div>
  <p>Move</p><p>this</p><p>DIV</p>
  <select name="cars" id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue lies here:

```js
function dragMouseDown(w) {
  w = w || window.event;
  w.preventDefault();
  pos3 = w.clientX;
  pos4 = w.clientY;
  document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
  document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
}
```

Where **you preventing the default action** so remove [`w.preventDefault();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) *(This tells the user agent that if the event does not get explicitly handled, its default action should not be taken as it normally would be)* and you will be fine.

```js
function dragMouseDown(w) {
  w = w || window.event;
  pos3 = w.clientX;
  pos4 = w.clientY;
  document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
  document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
}
```